# How do you organize your papers?

Tags: soft-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use any article organizers?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/do-you-use-any-article-organizers)

[[ This is intended as a wiki question ]]

I have tons of papers on the subject I'm studying.  When you get them from ACM or someone's website, they're usually called something like `kautz-a1.pdf` or, my favorite, `paper.pdf`.  What I've done is organize them by:

```
year - first author's last name - paper title.pdf
```

So for example, in /papers:

```
2007 - Wang - PRT for RT indirect lighting using spectral mesh basis.pdf
```

This seems to work, and I can usually find what I'm looking for.  I mirrored this folder on DropBox, so I can pull down the collection if I happen to be working on another computer than my main.

How do other people store them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/), which allows you to tag your papers, find them by topic, author, export bibtex files, and so on.