# Tool for managing scientific papers

Tags: soft-question, software, citations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you use any article organizers?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/do-you-use-any-article-organizers)

As part of my Ph.D. studies I need to create an overview of recently (since 2000) published papers with impact on my study field.

Creating a list of articles isn't a problem, but what I also want to do is to follow the most cited articles and authors (after I'm done with this).

Is there some tool, that would allow me to store the articles and then simplify the most cited authors/articles search?

Comment: You can always write a small program to do that for you :-) For Mac you have Papers (http://www.mekentosj.com/papers/), though.

Comment: I think this is off topic.

Comment: @Tyson: we've had other similar questions about tools for academics and paper writing, so I'll allow it to stay.

Comment: Mendeley? (http://www.mendeley.com/)

Comment: @AnthonyLabarre Thanks for pointing out the duplicate, but questions about tools should definitely be allowed (even though there aren't many TCS related tools).

Comment: related [meta thread](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/358/186), if you want to argue for reopening the question please use that discussion. (I am personally in favor of reopening that question).

Comment: before reopening, it would be nice to know the ways in which the marked duplicate question does NOT answer the OP's question here.

Comment: in particular, why: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2939/tools-for-organizing-papers does not answer the OPs question